# Useful services where I can create a photography website/blog?

Tags: digital, web, stock-photography, publishing, blog

I am interested in publishing some of my photography on the internet. I have looked at creating blogs or websites using blogger or wordpress, however a lot of the photography themes cost +$70, as this is a non-profit/personal website, I am not looking to pay much for it. Also I am not great with HTML 5 and am not looking to hire a developer to create a website. I was wondering if anyone knew any programs/websites that offer customisable photography templates or where I can create my own website easily?

Comment: There are many services that allow you to do that. If you just want to showcase your work there are free services like Flickr and 500px. They lack the blog feature however. If you're interested to sell your services as a professional photographer services like the website builders Squarespace and SmugMug are popular. They are not free however and might be over your budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with WordPress, I'd recommend you take a look at the Keres theme.  It's not free, but it's pretty powerful and only $45.  It was the one I ended up settling on for [my Photography site](https://ajhendersonphotography.com) and it has some pretty nice gallery options available.

Comment: I like the look of your website! If I were to perhaps sell my prints on the site would wordpress be capable of handling it for that specific theme?

Comment: @user3731036 - the most recent version of that theme does support integration with a web-shop plugin.  I have not tried it though as I don't need to do sales on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You pay people to do certain things (design / hosting etc) because you either can't do it yourself, or you don't have time.

The cheapest way would be to use a self-hosted (raspberry pi - anyone?) platform such as [Koken](http://koken.me/) and do it that way. However, paying for a service such as photoshelter means you can spend more time shooting and less time making a website.